# Getting Row Count Zero in DataSet

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, dataset, datareader

I have a method that returns LoginStatus from Sql. The Stored procedure is at bottom of question.

On running, I am only able to get Column at [2] from DataSet. Row Count is always 0.

```
DataSet logStatusDs = new DataSet();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetLoginStatus(Convert.ToInt32(Session["userid"]));

    string aa = logStatusDs.Tables[2].Rows.Count.ToString();

   // if (aa == "In")
   // {
   //    btnCheckout.Visible = true;
   // }
   //else
   // {
   //    btnCheckIn.Visible = true;
   // } 
}

public DataSet GetLoginStatus(Int32 userId)
{
    //DataSet logStatusDs = new DataSet();
    //load the List one time to be used thru out the intire application
    var ConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EMSJConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("get_LoginStatusQ", connStr))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Session["userid"]);
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(logStatusDs);
        }
    }

    return logStatusDs;
}
```

Stored Procedure Used:

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_LoginStatusQ]  
@UserId int
AS   
BEGIN  
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT TOP 1 UserTimeId, LoginStatus 
  FROM UserTime 
  WHERE UserId = 2 
  ORDER BY UserTimeId DESC
END
```

Comment: How do you know the data is stored in `Tables[2]`, and not `Tables[1]` or `Tables[10]`? And how could `Rows.Count.ToString()` ever equal "In"?

Comment: I have 3 Columns in Database. 3rd column is what i want. Sorry , donot consider if condition.I put it by mistake. Let me update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_LoginStatusQ]  
@UserId int
AS   
BEGIN  
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT TOP 1 UserTimeId, LoginStatus 
  FROM UserTime 
  WHERE UserId = @UserId  
  ORDER BY UserTimeId DESC
END
```